# Seventies SF zombie film title

Tags: story-identification

I saw a movie in the mid 70's about Burt Lancaster (I think) as the only human in a world of flesh eating zombies - it had a funny name -

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175128/1980s-vampire-movie-name (which is newer but has a confirmed answer)

Answer (score 5):

"The Omega Man" with Charlton Heston?

From the minimal clues provided:

- Mid 70s. Omega Man 1971.
- Burt Lancaster. To the best of my knowledge, Lancaster never made a Zombie flick. Another big name, Charlton Heston, did. It's also a very famous one.
- Only human. Check.
- Zombies. Yes, although they're not, to the best of my recollection, referred to explicitly as such in the movie.
- Flesh eating. No. However they were homicidally psychotic (imdb description).
- Funny name. ???

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067525/

> Due to an experimental vaccine, Dr. Robert Neville is the only survivor of an apocalyptic war waged with biological weapons. The plague caused by the war has killed everyone else except for a few hundred deformed, nocturnal people calling themselves "The Family". The plague has caused them to become sensitive to light, as well as homicidally psychotic. They believe science and technology to be the cause of the war and their punishment, and Neville, as the last symbol of science, the old world, and a "user of the wheel", must die. Neville, using electricity, machinery, and science attempts to hold them at bay.

Comment: If you go back to the mid-60s you will find a movie called The Last Man on Earth with Vincent Price which what they copied when they made The Omega Man, Or for a real treat read "I Am Legend" by Richard Matheson which was the books the movies were made from.