# 1980s Vampire Movie Name

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I am trying to find out the name of a vampire movie that used to come on TV all the time when I was a kid. This was probably in the early to mid 90s, so I think the movie was from the 1980s.

It was a vampire type movie where the virus made everyone extremely pale and they wore black robes. The main characters were trying to hide in a large house and one of them wore a black motorcycle vest with 2 red fists with middle fingers raised on it.

At the end, the main leader of the cult was killed in a fountain I think. It seems like it was called the family, or that is what the vampires we're called. I have tried to find the name for years and can't seem to find the right Google keywords so I was hoping someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 12):

Could this be the 1971 film [The Omega Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Omega_Man)?

In this film, based on the novel I am Legend by Richard Matheson, most of the world has been killed by biological weapons from a war between the USSR and China. A scientist discovers how to become immune to the plague which has destroyed the world and spends his days hunting members of a group of nocturnal albino mutants called "The Family." It is the main character who dies in a fountain, however, not the leader of The Family.

Comment: That is it!!! Last time I saw that movie I was probably 7, so I guess my memory was off more than I thought. Amazing that you were able to know that from my little info. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user92912, you should accept this answer then. And I wouldn't be offended by an up vote.