# Old movie where a fortress-type home comes under attack by hooded beings with an aversion to light

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The movie is likely from the seventies and I saw it as a kid.

Takes place in post-apocalyptic Earth, or at least the desert. There is a large fortress-type home where the protagonist lives, and he goes out freely during the day, but must return home by night time. At night, lights shine brightly around the fortress and hooded beings try to get in, but they are turned back by the light. When there is some kind of power failure, the beings are able to infiltrate the home fortress.

Thanks for any ideas you might have!

Comment: Can you clarify whether the movie you're thinking of was in colour or black & white?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Wrong answers give you an excellent chance to [edit] your question with details that you now realize were there.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175128/1980s-vampire-movie-name

Answer (score 14):

The Omega Man (1971)

It sounds like this adaptation of Richard  Matheson's 1954 novel "I Am Legend". A plague changes most of humanity into mutated, light sensitive 'vampires'. Here is a trailer from YouTube:

Comment: Even if it's not this particular iteration, there's other movie productions of "I Am Legend" that this may relate to.